# Flutter Invalid constant value for padding value

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, padding

I have a `Widget` wrapped in a `Padding`. I would like to have `rightPadding` respectively to the `width` of the current device.
This is what I tried:

```
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 8,
        bottom: 8,
        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30), // -> error
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/person.png'),
  ),
```

But I get the error:

> Invalid constant value

Why is that and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you're assigning the entire widget as a constant, then you can't have a variable value like the right one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove `const` before `EdgeInsets`. Why? Because it can't be constant if you are using var(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width).

Try this:

```
child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 8,
        bottom: 8,
        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30), // -> error
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/person.png'),
  ),
```

Comment: that was it, thanks! but why is the `const` there in the first place?

Comment: const is there to be build in the compile time. That way it is faster than rebuilding it each time. The downside is, you can't use dynamic values(vars) since you are setting the `right` padding at runtime, the compiler is complaining.

Please mark as solved. Thanks!

Comment: This is a correct answer, I remove the `const` keyword from parent widget and it does solve it